# WP-Woocommerce internal server error 500 code snippet

Tags: php, wordpress

When I add this code to functions.php
I get internal server error....
what's wrong?

Purpose of the snippet: This code is to replace prices in products that have variations (price 1, price 2) it will output "from 1$" showing the lower price...

after debbuging got this from the log:

```
 PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/organicb/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:20) in /home/organicb/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php
```

snippet was found in https://gist.github.com/kloon/8981075

```
 // Use WC 2.0 variable price format, now include sale price strikeout
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
    function wc_wc20_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
        // Main Price
        $prices 
        = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
        $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'Desde: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
        // Sale Price
        $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
        sort( $prices );
        $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'Desde: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

        if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
            $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
        }
        return $price;}
```

Comment: What is the use of this code?

Comment: This code is to replace prices in products that have variations (price 1, price 2) it will output "from 1$" showing the lower price...

Comment: do you have any hint why this snippet is breaking the site?

Answer (score 0):

You should develop  with wp_debug enable. In your wp-config.php file, search for:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

and change to:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: will try that. thanks. I cant seem to find the error... is there a error log? seems that my ajax shopping cart and the snippet make a conflict... sometimes gives error 500 other times not...

Comment: use this to wordpress create a log file define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

Comment: thank you very much, got the log... apparently this is the problem with my snippet, ` PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/organicb/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:20) in /home/organicb/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121`